# Why do I get NSUnknownKeyException when I click on a button?

Tags: ios, swift

> app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
>   '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:
>   this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key button_1.'

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func button1_pressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    NSLog("hello");
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have no outlet defined (anymore). The storyboard still thinks there is an `@IBOutlet weak var button_1: UIButton?` but you have deleted it apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Check storyboard or xib (whichever you're using). The most likely source of this error is that something has a connection to an action or outlet that doesn't exist in the code.